# Как вывести повторяющиеся элементы после группировки?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица с колонками a и b, обе колонки типа INT. Дан запрос:

`select a, count(*) from t group by a`

Как изменить этот запрос, чтобы вывелись уникальные значения “a” которые встречаются в таблице более 2-х раз?

Comment: [having](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_having_clause.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для такого простого и having подойдет. Для более сложных используются временные таблицы

```
SELECT a, count(a) AS count 
FROM t 
GROUP BY a 
HAVING count > 2
```